How should thread_local unique_ptr<class> be used to prevent memory leaks
A colleague wrote this:
namespace {
    thread_local constinit int lastY = -1;
    thread_local std::unique_ptr<AvxBezierAndSaturation> pAvxBezierAndSaturation{};
}

void Class::functionName(....)
{
  :
        if (!static_cast<bool>(pAvxBezierAndSaturation))
            pAvxBezierAndSaturation = std::make_unique<AvxBezierAndSaturation>(bufferLen);
 
}

When the program terminates all instances of AvxBezierAndSaturation and storage allocated by it are reported as storage leaks by VLD.
Is this correct usage of thread_local unique_ptr and if not how SHOULD it be used??
Thanks
David

You can also create a std::shared_ptr in the function starting the thread and then passing it by value using a lambda expression to a std::thread/std::jthread or std::async call. Thread local storage is then not needed.

Memory leak detector might have issues with globals which might be destroyed after the memory leak reporter.

I mean, you did "leak" them, in that a pointer is created and left around forever for each thread that calls this code?

"...When the program terminates..." do all threads using thread_local exit cleanly before main exits ?

Leaks on program termination are not leaks. Also, thread_locals get destroyed when the thread dies -- how exactly are you terminating the program, and are you cleaning up all the threads? Also, you don't need the cast to bool -- happens automatically in a boolean context.


Leaks on program termination are not leaks
These leaks occurred long before termination. That's just when VLD reports the leak has occurred.

The threads that allocated the storage should have terminated long ago as they were openmp threads

Please provide [mcve]. I don't have VLD, but valgrind doesn't show any leaks. If I make some assumptions about your AvxBezierAndSaturation and everything else of course, because you didn't show your code.

I think the problem here is the threads in question are OpenMP threads and don't get terminated.  Still investigating

The most likely problem is probably that not all of your threads have terminated when your program exits.
Given that you're using openmp there's probably a good chance that those belong to openmp.

1. C++ Standard
There are two cases how the lifetime of thread_local variables can be ended in the standard:

the thread returns from its initial function
std::exit() is called
This will destroy all thread_local variables of the thread that called std::exit.
But NOT for any other threads that might still be running apart from the one that called std::exit.
Note: returning from main() will call std::exit() for you.

This is covered by:

6.9.3.4 Program execution - Start and termination [basic.start.term] [emphasis mine]
(2) Constructed objects with thread storage duration within a given thread are destroyed as a result of returning from the initial function of that thread and as a result of that thread calling std​::​exit. The destruction of all constructed objects with thread storage duration within that thread strongly happens before destroying any object with static storage duration.


17.5 Startup and termination [support.start.term] [emphasis mine]
[[noreturn]] void exit(int status);

(9) Effects:
(9.1) - First, objects with thread storage duration and associated with the current thread are destroyed. Next, objects with static storage duration are destroyed and functions registered by calling atexit are called. [...]

So as long as you ensure that no other threads are running when you call std::exit (either implicitly by returning from main() or explicitly) then all thread_local variables should be properly cleaned up.

2. MSVC + openmp
I'm going to assume that you're using msvc & openmp, given that you're using vld (and mentioned openmp in the comments).
OpenMP is not part of the C++ standard, so the rules might be slightly different.
The OpenMP documentation for MSVC contains the following passage:
(note that openmp threadprivate, __declspec(thread) and thread_local are all the same thing in msvc)

OpenMP library reference - Directives - threadprivate
threadprivate
Remarks
[...]
A threadprivate variable of a destructible type isn't guaranteed to have its destructor called.
[...]
Users have no control as to when the threads constituting the parallel region will terminate. If those threads exist when the process exits, the threads won't be notified about the process exit, and the destructor won't be called for threaded_var on any thread except the one that exits (here, the primary thread).
So code shouldn't count on proper destruction of threadprivate variables.

i.e. if you're using openmp there is no guarantee that destructors for thread_local variables will be called.

3. Workarounds
One option would be to not use a thread_local variable, but rather place it on the stack of the threads that need it.
openmp has the private clause for this (or firstprivate / lastprivate / copyprivate)

Another option would be to just ignore the leak (if all the destructor does is freeing some memory then there's no real harm on skipping it on process exit).
Note that if you're writing a DLL (this does not apply to executables), then the recommended practice for static variables and / or thread local variables with non-trivial destructors is to intentionally leak resources on process exit:

Thread Synchronization in DllMain during Process Exit

By the time DllMain is called at process exit, all the process’s threads have been forcibly cleaned up and there is a chance that the address space is inconsistent. Synchronization is not required in this case. In other words, the ideal DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handler is empty.
Windows Vista ensures that core data structures (environment variables, current directory, process heap, and so on) are in a consistent state. However, other data structures can be corrupted, so cleaning memory is not safe.
Persistent state that needs to be saved must be flushed to permanent storage.



If you absolutely need those destructors to run then you'll have to manually track them so that you can call their destructors at exit.
This does come with a cost though - each thread_local variable needs to register at construction and unregister at destruction, which requires synchronization between the threads.
For example like this:
class shutdown_manager {
public:
    using token = std::list<std::function<void()>>::iterator;

    static inline shutdown_manager& instance() {
        static shutdown_manager sm;
        return sm;
    }

    token register_shutdown(std::function<void()> shutdownfn) {
        std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
        return exit_callbacks.emplace(exit_callbacks.end(), std::move(shutdownfn));
    }

    void unregister_shutdown(token t) {
        std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
        exit_callbacks.erase(t);
    }

private:
    shutdown_manager() = default;

    ~shutdown_manager() {
        for(auto& fn : exit_callbacks) {
            fn();
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::list<std::function<void()>> exit_callbacks;
};

template<class T>
class shutdown_aware {
public:
    template<class... Args>
    shutdown_aware(Args&&... args) {
        value.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        registration = shutdown_manager::instance().register_shutdown([&]() {
            value.reset();
        });
    }
    ~shutdown_aware() {
        shutdown_manager::instance().unregister_shutdown(registration);
    }

    // TODO: could add a more ergonomic API (for example like std::optional)
    T& get() { return *value; }
    void set(T const& v) { value = v; }

private:
    std::optional<T> value;
    shutdown_manager::token registration;
};

which then allows you to declare thread_local variables that will always be cleaned up like this:
godbolt example
thread_local shutdown_aware<std::unique_ptr<AvxBezierAndSaturation>> pAvxBezierAndSaturation = {};

// accessing unique_ptr:
auto& value = pAvxBezierAndSaturation.get();
// value will by of type std::unique_ptr<AvxBezierAndSaturation>&

There's a small caveat with this approach though:
The destructor of your thread_local variables might now be called during static variable destruction (from the shutdown_manager destructor), so accessing global variables in your destructor will no longer be safe.

Very nice answer
